# Javascript won't work with php variabiles

Tags: javascript, php

I have a big problem with my php & javascript code.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($doquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {



            echo ("

            <!-- Inizio Item-->
                <script type='text/javascript'>

                var end = new Date('".$row['fine']."');


                var _second = 1000;
                var _minute = _second * 60;
                var _hour = _minute * 60;
                var _day = _hour * 24;
                var timer;

                function showRemaining() {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var distance = end - now;
                    if (distance < 0) {

                        clearInterval(timer);
                        document.getElementById('countdown".$row['id']."').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                        return;
                    }
                var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

                document.getElementById('countdown".$row['id']."').innerHTML = days + ' Days ';
                document.getElementById('countdown".$row['id']."').innerHTML += hours + ' Hours ';
                document.getElementById('countdown".$row['id']."').innerHTML += minutes + ' Mins ';
                document.getElementById('countdown".$row['id']."').innerHTML += seconds + ' Secs';
                } 
                </script>
                <div id='countdown".$row['id']."'></div>
           ");
}
```

If i use this code, i get this in the countdown:

```
NaN days NaN Hours Nan Mins NaN Secs
```

i've checked the output of

```
$row['fine'];
```

and the output it is in the right form asked from javascript. Infact, the output is  `08/01/2017 3:45 PM`

Infact, if i try to put the date directly in the code, like this:

```
... 
var end = new Date('08/01/2016 3:45 PM ');
...
```

it shows the timer as it is supposed to do.

Comment: it is a bad idea having javascript inside the loop, imagine if you have 10 rows of data, it will duplicate the script 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I assume you have only 1 row of data) and tell me the result:-

```
$time_data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($doquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$time_data['fine'][]=$row['fine'];
$time_data['id'][]=$row['id']
}


            <!-- Inizio Item-->
                <script type='text/javascript'>

                var end = new Date('<?php echo trim($time_data['fine'][0]); ?>');


                var _second = 1000;
                var _minute = _second * 60;
                var _hour = _minute * 60;
                var _day = _hour * 24;
                var timer;

                function showRemaining() {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var distance = end - now;
                    if (distance < 0) {

                        clearInterval(timer);
                        document.getElementById('countdown<?php echo $time_data['id'][0]; ?>').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                        return;
                    }
                var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

                document.getElementById('countdown<?php echo $time_data['id'][0]; ?>').innerHTML = days + ' Days ';
                document.getElementById('countdown<?php echo $time_data['id'][0]; ?>').innerHTML += hours + ' Hours ';
                document.getElementById('countdown<?php echo $time_data['id'][0]; ?>').innerHTML += minutes + ' Mins ';
                document.getElementById('countdown<?php echo $time_data['id'][0]; ?>').innerHTML += seconds + ' Secs';
                } 
                <div id='countdown<?php echo $time_data['id'][0]; ?>'></div>
```

Comment: @MicheleGuidetti try putting `console.log(<?php echo trim($time_data['fine'][0]); ?>);` see what result do you get.

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on line 266 (in my .php file) wich is in

        var _second = 1000;

Comment: Don't copy blindly from the code given, you given incomplete code, I just copy and paste based on your code and made few modification

Comment: I have done modifications too, i did not copy blindly. (I have edited the code in the main question now)

Comment: try change quotes ' on double " in php

Comment: Try console.log variable `end`

Comment: @PiotrKazuś i've tryed but same error.
i get this: "Mon Aug 01 2017 15:45:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)"

Comment: Haha! I think I know the problem, from the comment you mention, the value from PHP is english, that's why it doesn't work! It should be `08/01/2016 3:45 PM` but your mysql result return as `Mon Aug 01 2017 15:45:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)`?

Comment: Yeah but the field in mysql is "TEXT", so why it returns " Mon Aug 01 2017 15:45:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)" instead of "08/01/2016 3:45 PM" as set on mysql? even if i check the output with "echo $row['fine'];" it returns "08/01/2016 3:45 PM" (PS, i understood the issue with console.log(end) right now ahah)

Comment: Then try 
new Date('<?php echo trim($time_data['fine'][0]); ?>').toUTCString() 
check if this works